# Do I need to specify the content type for encrypted string?

Tags: encryption, content-type

My script returns an encrypted string but, by default, it's in text/html content type. Should I specify the content type to text/plain instead?

I know it does not harm anything, but what is the right content type for encrypted string?

**Updated**: string was encrypted using [mcrypt_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php). There is no concern about security for this data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The correct content-type for "a stream of bytes" is application/octet-stream. At its most general, encrypted data is just "a stream of bytes." That said, many other content types may be appropriate depending on the exact format. For instance, if you were working with the [OpenPGP format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3156), it defines specific format types that are used, including `application/pgp-encrypted` and `application/pgp-signature` as part of a multipart/encrypted message. You are free to invent your own specifications within the MIME framework.

But if you don't have anything better to apply, and don't want to invent anything, the correct fallback is `application/octet-stream`, which means "here are bytes; please pass them along without interpretation."

It's unclear what you mean by "an encrypted string," but if you mean you've encoded these bytes into UTF-8 or ASCII (using Base64, for example), then `text/plain` is acceptable if you don't want to express anything more about the data. `text/plain` does suggest that it's human-readable, but you're at least expressing that it's displayable (it doesn't include control characters or other non-printables), so that's not unreasonable. `text/html` wouldn't make any sense here, since you don't intend it to be interpreted as HTML.

The major difference in practice between `application/octet-stream` and `text/plain` is that browsers and browser-like things will tend to download and save `application/octet-steam`, and will tend to display `text/plain`. Which behavior you would prefer should drive your choice.

Comment: Encrypting with mcrypt doesn't change much about the question. You're generating a sequence of encrypted bytes. If that's exactly what you're outputting, then application/octet-stream is appropriate unless you want to create some other semantic wrapper around it.

Comment: It's exactly what I am outputting. Thank you!